# How did the Voyager crew repair the huge hull breach in "Unimatrix Zero, part 2"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

After taking a hit from a Borg tactical cube with their shields down, the *Voyager* crew repairs the hull breach. How were they able to repair it and so quickly? I think it was even repaired later in that episode.

Comment: Normal way would be to replicate patch to the hull and then apply to the damaged section. All throughout ST-universed shows are frequent references to SF engineers' efficiency and work quality. In this case, as long as fuel conservation is not an issue, replication of every bit of missing hull would be a matter of minutes.

Comment: What's weirder is how often hull breaches seem to occur during the end-of-season finale episodes.

Comment: @Richard I always thought that particular hull breach was the biggest in the whole series

Comment: @Darren - True, but I'm guessing that once you fix the outside bits and re-route whatever was in that section, you can fix the inside bits at your leisure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Voyager suffers a [significant number of major hull breaches](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=inurl%3Achakoteya.net%20%22voyager%22%20and%20%22hull%20breach%22%20and%20%22repair%22) during its seven seasons in the Delta Quadrant. The typical chain of events appears to be:

1. A hull breach is detected (invariably during a firefight, but not always)
2. Force-fields seal off the affected area, preventing atmosphere loss
3. Repair teams are sent to fix the problems
4. The repair crews fix the breach from the inside out, presumably using a mixture of pre-made panels and replicated parts.

> **Janeway:** *There's a hull breach on deck four, forcefields in place, repair crews
> on the way*
>
> <sub><sup>[VOY: Alliances](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/211.htm)</sup></sub>

and

> **JANEWAY:** *Be ready to seal the hull breach with a force field. I'll have a damage control team standing by for repairs. And let's
> track it on sensors when it gets out*
>
> <sub><sup>[Voy: Heroes and Demons](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/111.htm)</sup></sub>

I see no reason why this shouldn't be the case in this episode as well. There's no clear indication of quite how long they spent repairing the ship although we do have a scene in which we see the crew putting the bridge back together and testing the shields and sensors.